# geom_signif: significance bars between bars separated by fill rather than factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

Any usage of geom_signif results in this error:
Error in f(...) : 
  Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis

I think it appears to be caused by the fact that I've separated my bars using fill= in the ggplot function so that I have grouped bars.

```
ggplot(Csummary, aes(x=reorder(Time,Cort), y=Cort, fill=Posthoc)) + 
labs(x = "", y = "Corticosterone (ng/mL)") + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity",colour="black") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Cort-se, ymax=Cort+se),
  width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) + theme_classic()  +    
  scale_fill_grey(start = .5, end = 1) + 
            guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT85a.jpg)

Trying to get comparison bars between the shaded bars in PP and H and between PP and H overall.

Should mention that I've also tried the older example:

```
 + geom_path(x=c(.75,.75,1.25,1.25),y=c(8,9,9,8)) + annotate("text",x=1,y=10,label="NS")
```

but it ends up not drawing a horizontal line

Comment: It looks like you have to manually supply x-values when you have dodged bars, see [the vignette here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html)

Comment: referring to `+ geom_signif(data=data.frame(x=c(.75, 1.75), xend = c(1.25,2.25), y=c(8,25), annotation=c("NS","*")))`, correct? this doesn't seem to work either, though this example does appear to be nearly exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Specifically, I get the unhelpful error message `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Posthoc' not found`...

Comment: You might be able to fix that by moving the `fill=Posthoc` aesthetic out of the top level and into your `geom_bar`, so `geom_bar(aes(fill=Posthoc), ...)`. If you need further help, please provide a reproducible example of your data so we can actually try your code.

Comment: Thanks, that's very nearly got it. Sig markers are on but it's reset my +/- error bars to pile on top of the factors. I'm enough of an R novice that I've no idea how to provide a reproducible example without providing all of my code and data, so I'll keep playing around.                                                             Which was solved by.... adding `(fill=Posthoc)` to `geom_errorbar(aes(...))`. Oddly it provides an error that it is ignoring that command, but then gives exactly the desired output.